# Fermat like equation for meromorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I found this question in Conway, and really have no idea how to answer it.  Can anyone provide any hints?

> For each integer $n\geq 1$ determine all meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ $f$ and $g$ with poles at $\infty$ such that $f^n+g^n =1$.

Comment: there are entire functions $a,b,c,d$ such that $f = a/c$ and $g = b/d$, and $f,g$ have their poles at the same points and of same order, so without any loss of generality we can suppose that $c = d$ ? this would reduce the problem to $a^n + b^n = c^n$ where $a,b,c$ are entire functions.

Answer (score 3):

From I. N. Baker, *On a class of meromorphic functions*. [Link to the paper in JStor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2036259?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A7d53a0492d27b2d256739ec3fce86f76&seq=1&loggedin=true#page_scan_tab_contents).

**For $n=2$:**

All solutions are of the form $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{2h(z)}{h^2(z)+1}\\g(z)&=\pm\frac{h^2(z)-1}{h^2(z)+1}\end{align}$$
for $h(z)$ any meromorphic function.

**For $n=3$:**

All solutions are of the form $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\wp'(h(z))}{\sqrt{12}}}{\wp(h(z))}\\g(z)&=\omega\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\wp'(h(z))}{\sqrt{12}}}{\wp(h(z))}\end{align}$$

where $\wp(z)$ is [Weierstrass elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions), for $g_2=0$ and $g_3=1$, and $\omega$ is a cubic root of $1$.

**For $n>3$:**

There are no meromorphic solutions.